# How to handle null return from Kotlin's find function?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

I have a list of objects, for example:

```
val companies = listOf(
        Company(id = "1", name = "IBM"), 
        Company(id = "2", name = "Apple"))
```

Next, I want to find an object from this list by `name` condition and get the value of an `id` field of the object found. So, I'm using `find` function calling on the list:

```
val companyId = companies.find { it.name == "IBM" }.id
```

But this one doesn't compile with *Only safe or non-call calls are allowed on a nullable receiver*. So, how should I handle the possible `null` return from `find`? I tried with an Elvis operator to return an empty String otherwise, like:

```
val companyId = companies.find { it.name == "IBM" }.id ?: ""
```

But that still doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to (because it cannot get the `id` from a null object unless you handle it as nullable (`String?`) again):

```
val companyId = companies.find { it.name == "IBM" }?.id ?: ""
```

If you are sure that there is a company with name "IBM" you can use `!!` (not recommended):

```
val companyId = companies.find { it.name == "IBM" }!!.id
```

[further more](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls)

Comment: Note that this will also return `""` if the company is found and its `id` is `null`.